# waveplay equivalent command in python

Tags: python, matlab, audio

My MATLAB code is:

```
x=wavread('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\FYP\1. Matlab Work\record work\Recording.wav',58368);
wavplay(x,58368)
```

Its equivalent code in Python is:

```
x= sio.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\Recording.mat')['Recording']
```

all I want to know is what is the **wavplay equivalent command in Python** so that I can play my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various tools for playing sound in Python.  The most direct equivalent is the [`play`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sounddevice/) method in the [sounddevice](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sounddevice/) package.

The easiest way to load the file is with [`read`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySoundFile/) method in the [soundfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySoundFile/) package.

Also note that `wavread` and `wavplay` were removed from MATLAB several years ago.  They no longer exist in recent version of MATLAB.  The functions I linked to are more generic functions/methods equivalent to the [`audioread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/matlab/ref/audioplayer.play.html) and [`audioplayer.play`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/matlab/ref/audioplayer.play.html) functions/methods that replaced `wavread` and `wavplay` in MATLAB several years ago.

Comment: From these methods and packages would I be able to **play** only **.wav** files or I can also **play .mat** files?

Comment: You can do both.  `sounddevice` can be used to play any numpy array (with the right dimensions).  It doesn't care where the numpy array came from or how it was created.  So the numpy array could be loaded from a .mat file, just about any sound file (.wav, .mp3, .flac, .aiff, etc), a .csv file, an excel spreadsheet, a binary data file, etc.  Or you could generate the array manually, such as using a random number generator or generating a sin waveform.

Comment: I do `xx= scipy.io.loadmat('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Rabia Ahmad spring 2016\\FYP\\1. Matlab Work\\record work\\aa.mat')['aa'] sounddevice.play('aa.mat')` and the error I encountered is **TypeError: Unsupported data type: 'str192'**

Comment: and when i do `sounddevice.play(aa,64000)` then the error is **NameError: name 'aa' is not defined**

Comment: and also when i do `sd.play(xx,64000)` then the error is **sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening OutputStream: Invalid number of channels**

Comment: You can't play `aa.mat`, that is a filename, not an array.  And `aa` doesn't exist, you never define that variable.  MATLAB and numpy define array dimensions differently, typically 2D numpy and MATLAB arrays are transposed versions of each other.  So try `sd.play(xx.T, 64000)`.  That being said, loading the `.wav` file directly in Python using `audioread` will be much simpler and avoid all these problem.  It will put the numpy array in the right orientation, and avoid complications with having to deal with the MATLAB variable names (the `['aa']` part), and it will give you the sampling rate.